# How to send PostData request for NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutableurlrequest

I have URL which takes a parameter.  In Firefox. I have download add-on and find the parameter for the request.  I found PostData Tab on the httpFox add-on tool and I saw the parameter and value.

I created a string and added the parameter, and encoded that string value

```
NSString *parameterId = [NSString StringWithFormat:@"ac$2_sdrex_es34_4333f=Caa111"];

NSString EncodeID = [parameterId
  stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

...and created the PostData,

```
PostData = [encodeID  dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
```

...and set the postLength,

```
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
```

...and set the http header values,

```
[request setValue:postLength forHttpHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

and then make the connection,

```
connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

But this results in the following error...

```
Error Domain = NSURLErrorDomain code= -1002 unsupported url
```

I have encoded the URL too.

Can anyone advise me how to resolve this issue?

This is what after creating the postData!

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];    
    theRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];

    [theRequest setValue:@"win-eqjf1b1ep06:20000" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Host"];
    [theRequest setValue:@"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en-US; rv:1.9.2.10) Gecko/20100914 Firefox/3.6.10" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
    [theRequest setValue:@"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [theRequest setValue:@"en-us,en;q=0.5" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Language"];
    [theRequest setValue:@"gzip,deflate" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];
    [theRequest setValue:@"ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Charset"];
    [theRequest setValue:@"115" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Keep-Alive"];
    [theRequest setValue:@"keep-alive" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Connection"];


    [theRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
```

@all
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please also post the code you use to initialise the NSMutableURLRequest itself, thanks.

Comment: @snips i edited with NSMutableURLRequest!

Answer (score 0):

NSMutableURLRequest only supports http://, https://, ftp://, or file://

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i

Are you using some other protocol?

Comment: i am using http:// and i am using all the callback methods which is called the delegate method's